# customize Version History Form in doc lib

Tags: sharepoint-online, version-history

I would like to customize the version history form in my SharePoint 2013 Online App's document library with Visual Studio 2013.

I have created a button + script that keeps only the last version of each editor (named "versiebeperking"). Now I want to move this button from the document library view to the version history form (version history = versiegeschiedenis in dutch :)). See pic:

[image]

How do I achieve this? One way I can think of is that I add the button with jQuery when the Versions.aspx page loads, but how do I do that? Anything that points me in the right direction will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page that displays version is `versions.aspx` and this page resides in the `layouts` folder. Since its SP Online we don't have access on those files.

You can try loading that page into a div and check whether it can be manipulated using jQuery.

Update - Its a bad idea because `core.js` file I believe also resides in `layouts` folder.

Instead handle the button click event from the main page and use JavaScript object model to get the versions and display it in a custom dialog.

http://techfindings-prem.blogspot.com/2014/06/how-to-get-all-versions-of-list-using.html

Comment: Thanks, will try that. I also found that versions.aspx is called by a function in core.js, can't I just create a customversions.aspx that is called by a customcore.js? Only thing I would need then is the original source code of the version.aspx, which I can't find... Or is this a bad idea?

Comment: see my updated answer.

Comment: true, core.js also resides in the layouts folder, however I already have a customcore.js to eliminate ECB menu items on the same library, which works fine. The only thing missing now is the source code of versions.aspx which I cannot find anywhere... Will give your link a try now

Comment: thanks Amal, your link will do the trick, especially the last part :)